# Excel Formula is not referencing properly - formula is modifying

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Background information -
I have a macro-enabled workbook that interacts with SQL. After some cleaning steps are completed, it eventually runs an elongated list of Stored Procedures and pastes them in an external workbook. It has been working fine up until recently where many of the formulas that reference other tabs in the template are randomly having issues finding the reference...thus changes the formula. I have absolutely no idea how this is occurring.

Formula example:

```
=IF('16.17.A.SupCarrier'!U9="","",'16.17.A.SupCarrier'!U9)
```

Formula changes to:

```
=IF(['16.17.A.SupCarrier']'16.17.A!U9="","",['16.17.A.SupCarrier']'16.17.A!U9)
```

Comment: This only does it if the sheet does not exist in the workbook as it assumes that it is an external reference to a closed workbook and tries to make it correct.  If the sheet exists then it does not change the sheet reference.

Comment: The sheet exists. Formula works in the template before executing the stored procedures (via vba) in the other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth.....I found a "solution" to the problem. I was previously saving the document while another excel sheet was open which I assume could have been causing memory issues preventing it from saving properly. I saved this document without any other Microsoft apps open and the issue seemed to resolve itself without modifying any formulas.